# Why is my Array behaving differently outside of an AJAX function? (populating jsTree)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, xml, jstree

Long story short, I'm creating a JSON-like array for jsTree.  What I don't understand is why the array is perfect for my needs inside the AJAX success function, but broken *outside* of that function.  Check out the screenshot from my console dump, you can see the differences.  Why is it different inside of the function vs. outside of the function?

Essentially, I can't do what I need to do unless it's in the perfect format:  (myAry inside the function)

What gives, man?

```
var myAry = [];

$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "parents.xml",
dataType: "xml",
success: function(xml) {

    $(xml).find('group').each(function() {

      myAry.push({
        "id": $(this).find('GroupID').text(),
        "parent": "#",
        "text": $(this).find('GroupName').text(),
      });


    }); //end each loop

      //this array is PERFECT
      console.log(myAry);

      } //end success function
  }); //end ajax GET

  //THIS ARRAY IS BORKED
  console.log(myAry);
```

---

xml:

```
 <groups>
    <group>
        <GroupID>1</GroupID>
        <GroupName>Instructional Assistant</GroupName>
    </group>
    <group>
        <GroupID>2</GroupID>
        <GroupName>Technician</GroupName>
    </group>
    <group>
        <GroupID>3</GroupID>
        <GroupName>HR Specialist</GroupName>
    </group>
</groups>
```

[image]

Comment: Your ajax function is **asynchronous**.

Comment: Because the ajax takes some time to finish, but everything after it will run immediately. Just call another function at the end of your success callback to do whatever you want to do with the data.

Comment: You can call whatever function needs to process that array from within the success function, passing the array as a parameter

Comment: $.ajax is a asynchronous function. the console.log function is firing before the code in your success callback function, which is why your array is empty.

Comment: That all worked.  Thank you for helping me make sense of it!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it hits this line of code 1st;

`//THIS ARRAY IS BORKED
  console.log(myAry);`

Asynchronous Javascript 
before the Ajax call returns processes